# std::vector<std::unique_ptr<X>> member variable causing problems

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, unique-ptr

I'm getting an error with the following code in VS2013...

```
class Bob
{
private:
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<UnrelatedClass>> _aVector;
    inline Bob(const Bob & other) {};
    inline Bob & operator=(const Bob & other) { return *this; };
public:
    Bob();
    ~Bob();
    Bob(Bob && o);
};

class Fred
{
    friend class Bob;

    [... A few functions, Bob never used ...]
};
```

...which compiles fine with the removal of `friend class Bob;`. Is this a compiler error? I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

The error is as follows:

```
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(615): error C2248: 'std::unique_ptr<Unrelated,std::default_delete<_Ty>>::unique_ptr' : cannot access private member declared in class 'std::unique_ptr<Unrelated,std::default_delete<_Ty>>'
      with
      [
          _Ty=Unrelated
      ]
      c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\memory(1487) : see declaration of 'std::unique_ptr<Unrelated,std::default_delete<_Ty>>::unique_ptr'
      with
      [
          _Ty=Unrelated
      ]
      c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(614) : while compiling class template member function 'void std::allocator<_Ty>::construct(_Ty *,const _Ty &)'
      with
      [
          _Ty=std::unique_ptr<Unrelated,std::default_delete<Unrelated>>
      ]
      c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0(752) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::allocator<_Ty>::construct(_Ty *,const _Ty &)' being compiled
      with
      [
          _Ty=std::unique_ptr<Unrelated,std::default_delete<Unrelated>>
      ]
      c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\type_traits(580) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::allocator<_Ty>' being compiled
      with
      [
          _Ty=std::unique_ptr<Unrelated,std::default_delete<Unrelated>>
      ]
      c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\vector(650) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::is_empty<_Alloc>' being compiled
      with
      [
          _Alloc=std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<Unrelated,std::default_delete<Unrelated>>>
      ]
      c:\...\include\bob.h(51) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Unrelated,std::default_delete<_Ty>>,std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>>>>' being compiled
      with
      [
          _Ty=Unrelated
      ]
```

Research has lead me to understand this is the same error generated when `Bob` is copied. Therefore, copying the `std::vector`, therefore copying the `std::unique_ptr`

Comment: I guarantee you that it does not "compile fine", since you are missing semicolons everywhere. This code is a lie.

Comment: 2 missing semi-colons. Fixed. Can you help me now?

Comment: "I'm getting an error..." - ***WHAT ERROR DO YOU GET?***

Comment: OK, sorry about that. I clearly wasn't thinking when I posted. Could you take another look?

Comment: Maybe your class `Unrelated` does have a private move-constructor and/or a private destructor? Or it is not complete, only forward-declared? You need to shorten the code only the very minimum which is required to produce the problem and then show us the [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) resulting from that.

Comment: I'm having serious problems getting a SSCCE that breaks... I will work on it myself and post a solution here if I can figure it out. I'm very sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: Don't worry about wasting our time, but understand that asking you to create a proper SSCCE is something which you should always try to do as it will help you to solve problems on your own and to learn a lot more that just by having someone else fix your code. I prefer teaching you to fish instead giving you a fish :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution. It seems the problem was *partially* a compiler issue, mostly my fault. Updating my compiler resulted in a much better error message describing the use of a deleted function as the cause of the problem.

I traced the problem down to the following line:

```
_aVector.push_back(someUniquePtr);
```

Which should have been:

```
_aVector.push_back(std::move(someUniquePtr));
```

I'll just have to be more careful next time ;)